# Calling function using spread operators

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

Is there a way I could shorten this using spread operators so I am not having to call the createtab function over and over. Especially in cases where I have a much bigger and deeper navigation bar?

```
import React from "react";

function createTab(page, props) {
  return (<li className="nav-item">
  <a href={"#" + page} onClick={() => props.handlePageChange(page)} className={"nav-link" + (props.currentPage === page? " active" : "")}>
    {page}
  </a>
</li>)
};

function NavTabs(props) {
  return (
    <ul className="nav nav-tabs">
    {createTab("Home", props)}
    {createTab("About", props)}
    {createTab("Blog", props)}
    {createTab("Contact", props)}
    </ul>
  );
};

export default NavTabs;
```

Comment: `{["Home", "About", "Blog", "Contact"].map(item => createTab(item, props))}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send all the pages in array to createTab

```
   function NavTabs(props) {
      return (
        <ul className="nav nav-tabs">
             {createTab(["Home", "About","Blog","Contact"]  , props)}
      </ul>
      );
  };
```

And here in createTab function use pages array and render li elements

```
  function createTab(pages, props) {
       return pages.map((page, index) => (
               <li key={"Key-"+index} className="nav-item">
                   <a href={"#" + page} onClick={() => props.handlePageChange(page)} className={"nav-link" + (props.currentPage === page? " active" : "")}>
                      {page}
                   </a>
              </li>))
          };
```

Comment: This is perfect! Less code, much more scale-able.. Now I can load my menu bar from a table and such. A million thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can just put your "tabs" in an array, then call `map` to create components out of them

```
function NavTabs(props) {
  const tabs = ['Home', 'About', 'Blog', 'Contact'];
  return (
    <ul className="nav nav-tabs">
      {tabs.map(t => createTab(t, props))}
    </ul>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like `["Home","About","Blog"].map(tab => createTab(tab, props))`

```
   return (
    <ul className="nav nav-tabs">
     {["Home","About","Blog"].map(tab => createTab(tab, props))}
    </ul>
   )
```